# How to select latest of mysql group where another constraint is given?

Tags: mysql

I have seen plenty of similar questions asked:

Most starred one is this one:
[Retrieving the last record in each group - MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group-mysql)

But my question is different.

I would like to select latest of a group (each option_id) for 1 user. Not all latest and not all latest for all users.

Imagine table called "options":

```
+-----+-----------+---------+-------+
| id  | option_id | user_id | value |
+-----+-----------+---------+-------+
| 100 |         3 |       2 |  1000 |
|  99 |         3 |       2 |   500 |
|  98 |         3 |       2 |  1000 |
|  97 |         2 |       2 |     2 |
|  96 |         2 |       2 |     6 |
|  95 |         1 |       2 |    88 |
|  94 |         1 |       2 |    87 |
|  93 |         3 |       2 |  1000 |
|  92 |         2 |       1 |    85 |
+-----+-----------+---------+-------+
```

Expected result of the query for user_id=2:

```
+-----+-----------+---------+-------+
| id  | option_id | user_id | value |
+-----+-----------+---------+-------+
| 100 |         3 |       2 |  1000 |
|  97 |         2 |       2 |     2 |
|  95 |         1 |       2 |    88 |
+-----+-----------+---------+-------+
```

Pseudo query: 
`select latest (highest id) of each option_id where user_id=2`

This is what I tried:

```
SELECT * 
FROM options 
where user_id =2 and id IN (
    select max(id)
    from options
    group by option_id
)
```

It seems like it gives expected results but only for some option_id not all. So I would get row 100 and 95 only for user_id=2, but option_id 2 is missing in results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was as easy as:

```
SELECT * FROM dbName.options where user_id =2

group by option_id

order by id desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use an inner join

```
select * from  options o
inner join (
  select max(id) max_id, option_id 
  from options
  group by option_id 
) t on t.max_id = o.id and t.option_id = o.option_id
where  user_id= 2
```

Comment: Hi, this seems to give only partial results - just like the query I have been using in my question.

Comment: show me the exact result you obtain  ..  max(id)   ..because . group by option_id  must return a value for each option_id  ...  eventually check better for your real table content

Comment: User id is INT.

Comment: then check for the real content of your test data for id and option id

Comment: Triple checked  my table content and the query is missing some option_id... sqlfiddle is offline, otherwise I would have exported the table for you to see. :(

Comment: this is strange  anyway   when you can create a valid  sqlfiddle . comment me the link   so i can check the same situation as  yours